# How to read data sent from web api using signalr in angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I want to read data sent from asp.net web api through signalr in angular client.

For that, I created the Hub at my web api given below :

```
//ProgressHub.cs
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string data)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", data);
    }
    public async Task<string> GetServerTime(IProgress<int> prog)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                prog.Report(i * 10);
                // Call to your client side method.
                Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).progress(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        });

        return DateTime.Now.ToString()+" Test";
    }
}

//startup.cs
app.MapSignalR();
```

and in angular client ,

```
    private proxy: any;
    private proxyName: string = 'progressHub';
    private connection: any;
    constructor(){

    // create hub connection  
    this.connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:53642/");
    // create new proxy as name already given in top  
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);
    // call the connecion start method to start the connection to send and receive events.  
    this.startConnection();
    this.proxy.on('Send', (data: any) => {
      const received = `Received: ${data}`;
      alert(received);   //here i want to get the data
    });

  }
  startConnection(): void {
    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      console.log('Now connected ' + data.transport.name + ', connection ID= ' + data.id);
      this.proxy.invoke('GetServerTime', serverMessage => 
      {
           console.log(serverMessage) 
      });
    }).fail((error: any) => {
      console.log('Could not connect ' + error);
    });
  }
```

when I run debug application , client successfully get connected to signalr
console output:

```
Now connected webSockets, connection ID= 19156d89-d82c-46f9-a109-d8a4828f8ea9
```

but doesn't return any data that I want to be alert .

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Only for asp.net core

Use [@aspnet/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) package to work with SignalR

Example
    private hub;

```
this.hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/signalr")
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
  .build();

this.hub.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

Then listen in event send from server

```
this.hub.on("Send", (data) =>
  console.log(data);
);
```

Update

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Home page loaded at: {DateTime.Now}");
    return View();
}
```

You can view [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply .... but I am using asp.net web api...so for that I must use 'signalr' package in angular client....refer this ...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I tried your answer ..but is gives me error at 'this.hub.start()' ......  Error: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server

Comment: Sorry check my answer again. You need to use ASP.Net Core with this package

Comment: do you have any idea about asp.net web api.....? How should I get data from api through signalr ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer :

My new hub (at asp.net web api) as given below :

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public string msg = string.Empty;
        public int count = 0;

        public void CallLongOperation()
        {
            Clients.Caller.sendMessage(msg, count);
        }
    }
```

and in angular client (using signalr) :

```
constructor() {
    // create hub connection  
    this.connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:53642/");

    // create new proxy as name already given in top  
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);

    // call the connecion start method to start the connection to send and receive events. 
    this.proxy.on('sendMessage', (percentage) => 
    {
      this.onProgressReceived(percentage)
    });
    this.startConnection();
  }

  startConnection(): void {
    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      this.getProgress();
    }).fail((error: any) => {
      console.log('Could not connect ' + error);
    });
  }
  private getProgress(): void {
    this.proxy.invoke('CallLongOperation')
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('broadcastMessage error -> ' + error);
      });
  }

  private onProgressReceived(percentage: number) {
   //your code logic with data
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Github](https://github.com/narottamgoyal/api.signalR)

- Web API with **netcoreapp2.2**

  Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR**

> Now send signalR message like the below example

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IHubContext<SignalRHub> _hub;
        public ValuesController(IHubContext<SignalRHub> hub)
        {
            _hub = hub;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("clientMethodName", "get all called");
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{connectionId}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(string connectionId)
        {
            _hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("clientMethodName", "get called");
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

> Startup.cs

Client is running on port 4200 ("http://localhost:4200").

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace SignalRWebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/chathub");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

> SignalRHub.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRWebApp
{
    public class SignalRHub : Hub
    {
        public void GetDataFromClient(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("clientMethodName", $"Updated userid {userId}");
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("WelcomeMethodName", connectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

- Angular sample app

**Install signalR package**

> npm install @aspnet/signalr --save

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private hubConnection: HubConnection;

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:8080/chathub").build();

    this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
      console.log("connection started");
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    this.hubConnection.onclose(() => {
      debugger;
      setTimeout(() => {
        debugger;
        this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
          debugger;
          console.log("connection started");
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
      }, 5000);
    });

    this.hubConnection.on("clientMethodName", (data) => {
      debugger;
      console.log(data);
    });

    this.hubConnection.on("WelcomeMethodName", (data) => {
      debugger;
      console.log(data);
      this.hubConnection.invoke("GetDataFromClient", "user id", data).catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  }

  public stopConnection() {
    this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
      console.log("stopped");
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```