# What is the meaning of $connection. with Jquery (Signalr)?

Tags: jquery, angular, signalr

I'm using angular11 with jquery, I added a script as below:

```
let node = document.createElement('script');
let url=this.GlobalServ.BasicUrl+'signalr/hubs';
node.src = url;
node.id = 'signalr'
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

When I'm trying to use the content of Signalr/hubs file (In my case: "cloudsferWebHub") It doesn't work:

$.connection.hub.qs = { 'migration': this.contentData.Id };
var agents = $.connection.cloudsferWebHub;  //cloudsferWebHub is undefined

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use jQuery together with Angular. To use signalR in Angular, you can create a service that simply imports @aspnet/signalr (like import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr')

Comment: The @aspnet/signalr package is used for .Net Core.  And Im using .Net Framework I installed the signalr package: npm install signalr.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with ensuring that your order is correct in your angular.json file. Jquery must be loaded before signalR. See this [stackflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297637/how-to-hook-up-signalr-with-an-angular-7-application) for a much more detailed answer.